# How to have a separate kernel parameter for a newly created network namespace under Linux?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel

I am creating a new network namespace called *OAM*, along wit the *veth* interfaces to communicate between the new namespace and the default namespace:

```
$ sudo ip netns add OAM
$ sudo ip link add veth0 type veth peer name veth1
$ sudo ip link set veth1 netns OAM
$ ip netns exec OAM ip link set dev veth1 up
$ ip link set dev veth0 up
$ sudo ip netns exec OAM ip addr add dev veth1 192.168.0.1/24
$ sudo ip addr add dev veth0 192.168.0.2/24
```

Now I check the value of *ip_default_ttl* parameter from within the default namespace:

```
$ cat /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_default_ttl
64
```

It is set to 64. Next I check the same parameter in the newly created OAM namespace:

```
$ sudo ip netns exec OAM cat /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_default_ttl
cat: /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_default_ttl: No such file or directory
```

So, there isn't a copy of this parameter in the new network namespace.

If I try to test what is the value of TTL in both namespaces by using *ping*, I can see it's *ttl=64*:

Default namespace:

```
$ ping 192.168.0.1
PING 192.168.0.1 (192.168.0.1) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 192.168.0.1: icmp_req=1 ttl=64 time=0.072 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.0.1: icmp_req=2 ttl=64 time=0.060 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.0.1: icmp_req=3 ttl=64 time=0.053 ms
^C
--- 192.168.0.1 ping statistics ---
5 packets transmitted, 5 received, 0% packet loss, time 3997ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 0.036/0.051/0.072/0.016 ms
```

Newly created OAM namespace:

```
$ sudo ip netns exec OAM ping 192.168.0.2
PING 192.168.0.2 (192.168.0.2) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 192.168.0.2: icmp_req=1 ttl=64 time=0.042 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.0.2: icmp_req=2 ttl=64 time=0.030 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.0.2: icmp_req=3 ttl=64 time=0.053 ms
^C
--- 192.168.0.2 ping statistics ---
3 packets transmitted, 3 received, 0% packet loss, time 1998ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 0.030/0.041/0.053/0.012 ms
```

So it seems that even though the *ip_default_ttl* parameter is not present in the new OAM namespace, the value used is the same (ttl=64). 
I confirm that by logging in as root into another terminal and changing the ip_default_ttl value from 64 to 32 like this:

```
$ echo 32 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_default_ttl
```

Now if I retest the pings to check TTL, I get the same value of *ttl=32* in both default and OAM namespace:

```
$ ping 192.168.0.1
PING 192.168.0.1 (192.168.0.1) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 192.168.0.1: icmp_req=1 ttl=32 time=0.029 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.0.1: icmp_req=2 ttl=32 time=0.038 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.0.1: icmp_req=3 ttl=32 time=0.053 ms
^C
--- 192.168.0.1 ping statistics ---
3 packets transmitted, 3 received, 0% packet loss, time 2000ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 0.029/0.040/0.053/0.009 ms


$ sudo ip netns exec OAM ping 192.168.0.2
PING 192.168.0.2 (192.168.0.2) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 192.168.0.2: icmp_req=1 ttl=32 time=0.023 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.0.2: icmp_req=2 ttl=32 time=0.031 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.0.2: icmp_req=3 ttl=32 time=0.082 ms
^C
--- 192.168.0.2 ping statistics ---
3 packets transmitted, 3 received, 0% packet loss, time 1998ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 0.023/0.045/0.082/0.026 ms
```

So, it seems that the kernel parameter *ip_default_ttl* defined in the default namespace is used globally across all the network namespaces.

**Finally, my question is,** what if I want to have **different TTL values depending on different namespaces.** Is there a way to achieve that ? Is there a way to somehow clone the *ip_default_ttl* kernel parameter (or other ones which don't get copied) from default to a newly created network namespace and have a separate value ?

Thanks for your answer in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Different namespaces and thus containers, etc. operate within a single instance kernel, so parameters like `ip_default_ttl` are global.

You can however explicitly set `hoplimit` for routes:

```
# ip route change 192.168.50.0/24 dev xenbr0 hoplimit 32
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply.
What about /proc/sys/net/ipv4/tcp_max_syn_backlog parameter? I suppose it's also global then. Can I have a separate behaviour determined by tcp_max_syn_backlog parameter for a specific namespace ?

Comment: You can't, but you don't need to. It specifies _maximum_ backlog number, while actual number is provided to `listen()` system call.